# Printing a string in a PHP script breaks the following HTML tags

Tags: php

So I am new to PHP development, and have been testing out a few scripts recently.

One script that  I have attempted to create is one that retrieves the subscriber count of a given YouTube channel, and I have come up with the following script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Test project.
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $json = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=Stackoverflow&key={API_KEY}');
            $subscribers = json_decode($json);

            var_export(current($subscribers->items)->statistics->subscriberCount);

            print '<p>' . $subscribers . "</p>\n";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, this script seems to break the HTML document, because whenever the page is loaded any tags that come after the PHP script are removed.

Example (resulting HTML document after I use the script above):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Test project.
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        '1'
```

As you can see, the document does not end with the appropriate `</body>` and `</html>` tags which are present in the original document.

I have attempted to validate the PHP document using various tools online, but have not managed to figure out the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try a good IDE and install Xdebug on the testing server. Writing code without good debugging tools is a fool's errand.

Comment: `$subscribers` is an object, You can't print on object. (unless you have created the class yourself and have added a `__toString()`-method.)

Comment: Ah, it did seem to be a misunderstanding of the `var_export()` function. After removing the function call from the start of the line and replacing it with a variable (`$sub_count`) decleration, the issue was resolved. A beginner mistake on my end.

Comment: I created an answer with my comment and a couple of examples, so you can mark it as answered if it works for you.

Comment: @keyboardSmasher I will take another look into an IDE as well as Xdebug, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$subscribers` is an object, You can't print on object, unless you have created the class yourself and have added a `__toString()`-method.

This should work:

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=Stackoverflow&key={API_KEY}');
    $subscribers = json_decode($json);

    // Save the value in a variable first
    $count = current($subscribers->items)->statistics->subscriberCount;
    print '<p>' . $count . "</p>\n";

    // Or use it straight away
    print '<p>' . current($subscribers->items)->statistics->subscriberCount . "</p>\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think under syntax is wrong.
`print '<p>' . $subscribers . "</p>\n";`

How about make some temporal string variable to store $subscribers. ?